# Getting a variable via module.exports in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

I have a variable `var1` in a class `A.js` that is a module level variable. However, I have some unit tests that check to make sure the contents of `var1` are what I expect. To make it so my test file can access `var1`, I used `module.exports`.

A.js

```
var var1 = {};

function resetVar1() {
    var1 = {};
}
module.exports.resetVar1 = resetVar1

function A() {
    // some init stuff
}

A.prototype.addVal = function (key, val) {
    // some code
    var1[key] = val;
    // some more code
}
module.exports.var1 = var1;
```

My test cases also run some code that update `var1` in `A.js`. When I run this code, it updates `A.var1` in my test file the first time, but then all other times, it isn't updated (example shown below)

testA.js

```
var A = require('A');

test('test1', function (assert) {
    var a = new A();
    a.addVal('key1', 'val1');
    console.log(A.var1); // prints {'key1': 'val1'}
});

test('test1', function (assert) {
    A.resetVar1();
    var a = new A();
    a.addVal('key2', 'val2');
    console.log(A.var1); // still prints {'key1': 'val1'}
});
```

`var1` in `A.js` behaves as expected. My question is why A.var1 is getting updated the first time I call addVal in `testA.js`, but not any other time?

Comment: I don't get it .. why are you creating a "new" A every test call?

Comment: Does creating a "new" A affect the value of A.var1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
module.exports.var1 = var1;
```

You are pointing `module.exports.var1` at the same object as `var1`.  That is presumably what you want.

But, when you then call `resetVar1()` with this:

```
function resetVar1() {
    var1 = {};
}
```

This assigns `var1` a new empty object.  But, `module.exports.var1` still points at the original object so nobody outside of this module will see the new variable.  If you truly want to reset a shared object to be an empty object, but you don't want to break the sharing, then you will need to not assign it a new object, but rather just remove all the properties on the existing object.

```
// remove all properties from the var1 object
// so we can clear it, but not break the references to it that others have
function resetVar1() {
    for (var prop in var1) {
         if (var1.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
             delete var1[prop];
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Added code example for a reset function that won't break the shared references.

Comment: Hmm I see, but why does `A.var1` get updated the first time I call `addVal`, but not the 2nd time?

Comment: @user1998511 - You will see it updated until you call `resetVar1()` which then makes the exported object be different than the one that is actually getting changed in the module.  So, `resetVar1()` breaks the shared object so what is exported is no longer the object getting changed.

Answer (score 0):

`module.exports.var1 = var1;` sets the value of the locally scoped `var1` variable (the initial empty object) to the exported property. When you later set a new value to `var1` inside `resetVar1`, the exported property still has the original object, so you get the same result.

Comment: I see, but why does `A.var1` get updated the first time I call `addVal`, but not the 2nd time?

Comment: Because in the first call, both the "local" `var1` and the imported `var1` point to the same object (the one you initially create)

Answer (score 0):

User jfriend00 is correct, you have to delete each property instead of assigning a new object.

Another approach is to use a `Map`, which has a `clear` method.

```
var var1 = new Map();

module.exports.var1 = var1;

...

function A() {}

A.prototype.addVal = function(key, val) {
    var1.set(key, val);
}

A.prototype.getVal = function(key) {
    return var1.get(key);
}

...

function resetVar() {
    var1.clear();
}

module.exports.resetVar = resetVar;
```